# Portable Socket programming in C/C++ possible?

Tags: c++, networking, boost

I am thinking of creating a multi-platform portable C++ server-client application. Is it even possible while using only standard libraries? If no, what other libraries are there?

Are there any improvements in this direction in C++11x? Like for threads, now we have std::threads.

To make it more clear.. I want something like boost::thread, which provides multiplatform portable multithreading, for networking.

And why C++ doesn't have libraries(standard) for such basic things like networking?

**Update**: Comparing to Python, which has everything (almost) built in to it... why not in C++?

Comment: Don't try to compare the Python standard library with that of C++. That will just annoy the snake and leave you disappointed.

Comment: Consider [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) and (possibly) [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html). I believe ASIO has been proposed for C++ TR2, so it's likely to end up in the standard library eventually, just hasn't yet.

Comment: @GregHewgill- Lol.. no offense, no war intended but I believe C/C++ are the most powerful(not feature rich or something) languages. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think you can measure languages on a single "more powerful / less powerful" dimension. Each language has their different purposes and sometimes one is more suitable than another. You have to consider aspects such as how long it's going to take you to write your code in the first place.

Comment: Oh, mr. questions. Networking is far, far, very far from a "basic" thing.

Comment: @GregHewgill- I agree, we cannot compare two languages, they have their different roles. By powerful, I meant raw power.. more closer to the system than others.. not sitting on top of abstractions which also means that many times we have to write more code than might have been required in other languages.

Comment: @VladLazarenko- That means I'm progressing.. YAY!! Thanks StackOverFlow :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html).  It has existed for "only" a small number of years...long ago we had [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html), but it feels dated now.

Comment: I always thought Boost Asio was for Asynchronous I/O as name says.

Comment: Socket programming is often, and perhaps best, done with asynchronous components.  The two go rather hand-in-hand (though Boost Asio does let you do things without sockets too).

Comment: `boost::asio` lets you do synchronous socket programming too.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard portable option in C++11.

However the portable boost::asio is one of the best networking API's. It is based on the proactor pattern which is very efficient.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: Is it for networking? I always thought it was for Asynchronous Input Ouput.

Comment: Yes it is for networking primarily. and the proactor is an Asynchronous model. It is very good in my usage.

Answer (score 3):

There have been *many* attempts to provide such a cross-platform library for networking over the years. The Berkeley socket library comes pretty close (and probably comes with your OS), but there are still platform-specific differences. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) has network socket classes that attempt to be cross-platform within the subset of platforms that Qt normally supports. You can probably find lots of others.

There is no *language* standard networking library for C or C++ analogous to `std::thread`.

Comment: I use Windows.. though I love Linux :D

Comment: The Winsock library that comes with Windows *is* the Berkeley socket library. You just need to call one Windows-specific function ([`WSAStartup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx)) and then you can use it normally.

Comment: So using that can I write a portable application, which can be compiled directly on different platforms without any changes?

Comment: Sure, you just need a few `#ifdef` conditionals for platform-specific bits.