# IS cURL a networking library?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, curl, poco-libraries

I am trying to learn network programming with C++, the portable way(not sticking to any particular OS). I asked in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814324/portable-socket-programming-in-c-c-possible) about a good portable networking library and experts(SO users) suggested of Boost::Asio and POCO.

Recently I stumbled back on cURL( I had heard about it, but forgot that there's something like that ). I know its a multi-protocol file transfer library, but isnt that what can be done with networking libraries?

My question is what is the usage of cURL? Is it another network library? If yes, isn't it good? Why no one suggested Curl? And if no, when to use it compared to networking libraries like Boost::Asio and POCO?

Comment: Someone down-voted my previous question, any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cURL is *primarily* for dealing with URIs/URLs. URLs are mostly used for networking, but at least in theory that's more or less incidental to cURL. Although it's probably not terribly common to do so, if you wrote a program that only dealt with local files, but did so using `file://` URLs, cURL would work fine for manipulating those local URLs.

Boost ASIO has infrastructure for doing networking, but nothing to work directly with URLs. Other parts of Boost include things like string handling that would probably be handy in building URI/URL handling, but as far as I know nothing that's specific to manipulating URIs/URLs.

POCO is a full-blown networking library, which does also include URI handling, but isn't devoted (anywhere close to) exclusively to it.

Comment: So can we say that cURL is at a higher level, another level of abstraction, providing URL specific networking whereas networking libraries(Boost::asio and POCO) are full blown libraries which can be used for any networking purpose including the one provided by cURL?

Comment: @questions: Yes, I'd say that's reasonably accurate.

Comment: Can you please give me some real life scenario where you'll use cURL instead of networking library and vice versa?

Comment: @questions: Sure. If I wanted to build something like (say) wget, I'd almost certainly use cURL. If I wanted to build a distributed file system, I'd probably opt for Boost or POCO.

Comment: Thanks Jerry.. you are always very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

cURL only allows you to make requests to URIs. It doesn't help you run a server or do low level network programming.

Comment: @Quentin- only HTTP? This is what I got from their site `supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and a busload of other useful tricks. `